# How search engine modify the page's url in browser's location bar to the real address

Tags: http, reverse-proxy

I'm writing a simple [reverse proxy program](https://github.com/xuelangZF/ReverseProxy) with flask.  After a suitable setting, when someone visit a site such as aa.com, he gets the content of bb.com in fact without awareness.  But when I want to proxy for search engine like google, I have little trouble.

I use anonymous.com as a agent of google.com, when someone visit anonymous.com, he get response from google actually.  When I search some keywords such as 'demo', anonymous.com shows visitor just the result looks like real google's search result, except the links contains google.com are converted to anonymous.com.  That's say all the result page's url such as

`http://google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpgP2Q3JrOAhWCjJQKHSMwAgEQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.demo.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEhAvTJreNJk_ukM_GYaLJwgHKHDw&sig2=Cll-LhXvW58WfthywPoH7A`

will turns to a new link:

`http://anonymous.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpgP2Q3JrOAhWCjJQKHSMwAgEQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.demo.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEhAvTJreNJk_ukM_GYaLJwgHKHDw&sig2=Cll-LhXvW58WfthywPoH7A`

Then when I click the new link, it open a new tab as well but the url address in the page's bar does not change to `http://www.demo.com/ehome/index.php?eventid=29414&` as the real google link do.  Why not?

Futher more:

1. What makes the url address changed when I visit a link such as google's search's result.
2. I notice the real page's address appear in the result link in google.com,  but in baidu.com, the link looks like `https://www.baidu.com/link?url=YvUsjKkfDWJgNAdKyIiWWwdYN1f7HKId8Jzw1LYtTTVpSjOVDzLcVcZ48nMjEqwpvvMtCZfXwmHRJoqZLOCFNq&wd=&eqid=c9a2689600068b8f00000006579c6198`, why does not this search engine just use the real url?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript code along with the page received checks the url's domain name and redirects the site to the original google.com.